# How to set shadow around grid in silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, shadow

I want to set Shadow effect around all sides of Grid.

I am using **DropShadowEffect** property of control to set shadow.

What i found is **Direction** property set shadow around control.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#F4F2F1" Width="300" Height="300">
        <Grid.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="300"
                              Color="#877b77"
                              Opacity="100"
                              ShadowDepth="10"
                              Direction="0" />
        </Grid.Effect>
    </Grid>
```

output I got is

as follows

[image]

What I want to shadow to be appear on all sides of Grid .

[I used this link to set direction property but its not giving me what i desire](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.direction%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

How do i set shadow to all direction?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You must set the `ShadowDepth` to 0 (shadow is directly underneath the border).